# Kubuntu 15.04 hangs after/during login

Tags: 15.04, wine, kubuntu, login

I am using Kubuntu 15.04 on my PC. The system worked fine until it broke a few days ago.

I was creating some data file backup copying files from one data disk to another data disk (the linux system disk was not involved) using luckybackup/rsync. The files were copied correctly but it took some time so I decided to start a game using Wine/PlayOnLinux. However the game (that used to work before) did not open up. Instead two of my three screens turned black. Only the backup output window stayed visible. I stopped the backup procedure and tried to shut down the system. That failed. So I forced a shutdown and booted the system.

Now after entering the password at login screen the cursor turns to a cross and all screens turn black. I can not do anything. Even starting some console by + does not work anymore (the mouse cursor hides but I can not see a prompt).

I tried to login using a different account... same problem.

The system had rebooted fine a few minutes before. I did not install new software or updates in between.

There is a lot of information in the Web about black screens after login but most of these cases are outdated and/or user account related while my problem is account independant. Anyway I tried some of those tips (starting Kubuntu in safe mode) but none worked.

So I (desperately) need beginners level help to fix the problem (without loosing all my settings and installed software if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

The backup copied the files from the given source to the given target. However the target /mnt/Backup/ was not the mounted backup disk (which was /media/Backup/) but a simple folder. This means the backup files were copied to the root disk causing the root disk to completely run out of space. This is why Wine crashed and why the system stopped working. After booting in secure mode and removing the misguided backup everything seems to work fine again now.